# How to get paypal checkout link in frontend sent by the backend

Tags: node.js, paypal, frontend, backend

I'm building a e-commerce and I'm using paypal API to get the payments, I have set everything up in the backend and I need to send the link generated by Paypal to my frontend in order to redirect the users to paypal checkout page.

I tried to send in res.status(200).send(link.href), but when it get to the frontend it's wrapped into a object and I can't figure out how to get it out of there...

this is my frontend:

```
const link = axios.post(`${baseApiUrl}/checkoutPayPal`, transaction)
            console.log(link)
```

and in the backend I did it:

```
paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                payment.links.forEach((link) =>{
                    if(link.rel === 'approval_url') res.status(201).send(link.href)
                })
            }
        });
```

if someone can help I'd be grateful!

Comment: is it wrapped in response object?

Comment: What does console.log(link) print?

Comment: Yes, it's wrapped in a response obj. It prints this:
`
{…}
​
_a: undefined
​
_c: Array []
​
_d: true
​
_h: 0
​
_n: false
​
_s: 1
​
_v: Object { data: "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-2GK5448373119180C", status: 201, statusText: "Created", … }
`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem! All I had to do was, using promisses, attach a 'then' clause to the axios request and my frontend is like this now:

```
 axios.post(`${baseApiUrl}/checkoutPayPal`, transaction)
                .then(res => window.location.replace(res.data))
```